# Are there Chinese approximations for the colloquial/slang English terms "snot rocket" or "bushman's blow"?

Tags: mandarin, vocabulary

In English I know of two colourful terms for blowing your nose without use of a handkerchief or tissue by holding one nostril closed and expelling mucus from the other:

- **bushman's blow** [[1]](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bushman%27s%20blow)[[2]](http://everything2.com/title/Bushman%2527s+blow)
- **snot rocket** [[1]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snot_rocket)[[2]](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=snot%20rocket)

<sup>(There are other terms too that I've learned since starting this question: *[farmer's blow](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=farmer%27s%20blow)*, *[farmers handkerchief](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=farmers%20handkerchief)*, *[bushman's hanky](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bushman%27s%20hanky)*, *[warehouse blow](http://everything2.com/title/warehouse+blow)*...)</sup>

In English we would never use the plain turn of phrase *to blow one's nose* for this act, even if we didn't know the slang/jocular terms I listed above we would use some circumlocution to describe the (to us) irregular method of nose blowing.

Yesterday morning I saw a nice young lady perform this manoeuvre in the street outside my hotel in a town outside Chengdu, Sichuan. This cemented the notion I already had that this act is not stigmatized in Chinese culture. But I'm not sure whether it's considered a normal or plain way to blow one's nose using the usual Chinese expression for nose blowing.

Is there a slang, jocular, or colloquial term (or any other kind of term) for this act in Chinese? (I'm most interested in Mandarin but other varieties of Chinese are also interesting.)

Comment: I LOVE THIS QUESTION!

Comment: Tried asking my SO this question but she tossed my phone back at me and screamed 恶心 so I'm not going to be much help but would love to see an answer, also in Australia we call this a farmers handkerchief

Comment: The key point of "bushman's blow" I've just learnt is **in the absence of suitable catching material, i.e. blowing your nose with no handkerchief or tissue or sleeve**, to the best of my knowledge, there's no equivalent Chinese term for this one. And for "snot rocket", the definition in Wiktionary seems just the "expelling" action without the *key point* above, we call it "[擤](http://www.zdic.net/z/1a/js/64E4.htm)[鼻涕](http://www.zdic.net/c/b/e/20552.htm)" in Chinese.

Comment: @Stan: Well that's just the current state of the Wiktionary definition that a random person off the internet added. I've always interpreted the phrase to refer to the act rather than the projectile. So the usual term for blowing one's nose in Chinese is 'xi bi ti' but the term for this style is 'xing bi ti'?

Comment: @50-3: I'm also an Aussie and have never heard *farmers handkerchief* before (-:

Comment: @hippietrail: "Blowing one's nose" is 擤鼻涕 (xǐng bí tì), it doesn't contain other information about *style*. But sorry, I can't recall any term read "xi bi ti", can you provide the corresponding Chinese characters?

Comment: @Stan: No sorry my Chinese is pre-embryonic so I just remembered it wrong, but the link you provided included the wording "to blow the nose with fingers" so that made me think it must contrast with the term I had asked a Chinese speaker about when I wanted "to blow my nose with a tissue".

Comment: @Stan: I found a second reference/definition of each term to provide greater depth/perspective in case any source is poor quality or biased.

Comment: @hippietrail really? Very popular in rural Victoria.

Comment: @50-3: In hunting additional definitions I came across more variants: "warehouse blow" and "farmers blow".

Comment: @Stan I think `xi bi ti` is 吸鼻涕?

Comment: I found my notes and indeed I was told 擤鼻涕 xǐng bítì.

Comment: The closest I couldn't think of is 随地擤鼻涕.

Comment: @NS.X.: You *couldn't* think of? It looks like you *could* (-:

Answer (score 2):

From the comments it seems like we've already established that blowing your nose is accurately translated as "擤鼻涕". As far as I can tell (from experience and further online research), there is no popular slang for doing so. The closest way to easily describe such action would be something like "不用纸擤鼻涕".

However, I should point out that this action is in fact pretty stigmatized in the Chinese culture, especially in more developed regions. Chinese people are simply less self-conscious about what others might think of their actions, which is why you'll still see people doing it.

Answer (score 0):

在中文的世界裡，沒有一個能夠清楚傳達(或是相對應) "Bushman's Blow" 的詞彙，

而上述的討論中，@hippietrail 所指的 "擤(ㄒㄧㄥˇ)鼻涕" 是 "Blow your nose".

若真的要闡述 "Bushman's Blow" ，"壓著一邊的鼻子，把鼻涕給噴出來" 則是可以被接受的。

PS：華人很少有 "Bushman's Blow" 這個動作，幾乎是 "Blow your nose" 比較多。

Comment: @People_in_Taiwan I would disagree with your PS, I see it on a daily basis, 老年男女。